# Excel VBA - Change tab colours based on user

Tags: excel, vba, tabs

I'm setting up a spreadsheet for multiple users on my team for testing purposes.
The idea is that a spreadsheet gets passed around and any feedback whether it be a pass or fail is noted on the spreadsheet.

I've currently added validation on certain cells which are red until something is filled in by, let's call them the primary tester.
I've added further validation via VBA to check that all red cells have something entered, otherwise the tab colour will turn red.

My problem is that the spreadsheet then gets accessed by the secondary tester then I want the tab to stay red until they have passed or failed the work (again based on cell validation).

So I think I've found a solution whereby the

In a module I've got:

```
Public Function UserName()
    UserName = Environ$("UserName")
End Function

Range("M5").Value = Environ("username")
```

In another worksheet I've got:

```
Set myRange3 = ActiveSheet.Range("P21")

  If UserName <> Range("M5").Value Then

            If UserName = Range("E15").Value Then

                If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(myRange3) = 0 Then
                    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Tab.Color = vbRed
                Else
                    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Tab.Color = xlColorIndexNone
                End If
            End If
  End If

'M5 = Primary tester
'E15 = Secondary tester
```

I expect the primary tester to have filled in all their requirements, making the tab turn from Red to neutral.
I would then expect the secondary tester to open up the spreadsheet and notice that a tab has been flagged as Red, meaning they need to add their validation of pass/fail for the tab to go neutral.

Comment: What's the issue exactly with your code? what is needed?

Comment: Yeah sorry I don't think it was clear.

So I just want to know if it's possible to get the worksheet tab colour to be red when another user opens the spreadsheet as they would have the "pass/fail" to fill in before it can be validated.

Comment: What happens when you run the code? Does it work as expected or does it throw an error?

Comment: Yes the code current executes fine, however the problem is that the tab isn't changing colour to red when another user opens the spreadsheet.

So my question is if it's possible to do this?

I believe the code is sound but I think it might be the way the code interacts when the second user opens the spreadsheet so it doesn't know to run the code like it would in a macro?

Comment: @Martin Mention my user name when responding or I may not get back to this post. For your question, yes it should be possible. Your code looks like it should work except you are setting the user name to "M5" but then checking "E15" for secondary user name. Are you populating "E15" somewhere else in your code? Have you verified on the sheet that these cells are populating as expected?

Comment: @K753 Thanks for the tip

Yes correct, M5 is set using the Environ variable. E15 is a drop down list of names which is set in cells in another worksheet. All the cells are currently populating correctly. My idea is if the user who opens the spreadsheet is also the same name in E15 then to flag the tab red as they have their part to complete on the spreadsheet (pass/fail check). Sorry if this sounds very strange, I'll try and be more clear as I know this project means nothing to anyone else :)

Comment: It seems like the first part of your IF statement will always be false. If the secondary tester opens the workbook their user name will be set to "M5" and the code will stop running.

Comment: @K753 To be honest, I'm not sure if what I want will even work looking at it with a fresh pair of eyes. The first part of the IF statement won't be false because the name in M5 is only stamped when a different routine is clicked (didn't know if that was worth mentioning). So once the secondary tester opens the workbook, M5 will be stamped as the primary tester and "UserName" will be the name of whoever has the workbook open, but it doesn't work :|

I think it might have something to do with where I've placed the code or may be it's just not possible?

Comment: @K753 So I managed to get the code working however....one last problem, which I'm hoping you can help with. So I've managed to get the tab to change colour when another user opens the workbook. The problem is, it seems the code only runs when something is entered in that worksheet. I believe this is because of the worksheet_change event that the code is in. So just wondering if there's a way to 'refresh' the code or get the code to run when the secondary user opens the workbook?

Comment: Good to hear you got the code working. You can put the code in Workbook_Open() and that should work. There is more info [here.](https://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/run-macro-automatically-opening-workbook/)

Comment: @K753 yeah I have tried that, but the code is specific to that worksheet so can't really be moved and I can't put the workbook_open() into the worksheet so kind of stuck. What I have done to temporarily get around this is to create a new routine worksheet_activate() and put the code in there so that when the secondary user clicks on the tab, it'll change to red. I'll keep this open if anyone else has any further suggestions, but thanks for your help!